# Figure position at bottom, when there is already one on top

Tags: floats, positioning

I am working on a LaTeX paper, using `RevTex 4.1` and the package `graphicx` and compiling with `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)`.

When I include figures in my document, they will automatically be placed on top of the page, which is in principle desired behavior. However, what I want to achieve now, is that a second figure on the same page appears on the bottom, instead of on top, automatically. I am looking for a compact solution which requires as little modifications as possible.

I am defining my figures using the `figure` environment and I am compiling with `latex`, which in my release is linked to `pdftex` if that matters.

I know that I can use `\begin{figure}[b]` for the figures, but I am specifically looking for an approach that handles this for me automatically when needed.

An minimal reproductive example would be as follows (note that this working example uses `article` instead `revtex-4.1`, but I would think that a solution that works for this example, would also work for my main document)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

The document puts both figures on top of page 1.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Add to preamble \def\fps@figure{tb}, this should help.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your comment. I extended my question with a stripped down document that still demonstrates my question.

Comment: @Zarko This still puts both figures on top.

Comment: I have the same issue with the `jfm` documentclass so it seems to be independent of the fact that you're using `RevTeX`.

Comment: @Zarko that just removes `p` from the default placement, so doesn't affect top/bottom float areas.

Comment: @David Carlise: indeed, you have right. It should be  \makeatletter \def\fps@figure{hbt}  \makeatother. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @Zarko that won't affect the document in the question, t and b are already in fps@figure the problem is that latex puts two figures in `t` and the OP only wants to allow one, fps@figure does not affect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{topnumber}{1}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for! Seems to work like a charm for my latex-document. Thank you!